# Remote desktop access to Ubuntu MATE 15.10

Tags: remote-access

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. My laptop runs Ubuntu MATE and I want to have remote access to it (like when I'm not at home). Can I access it from another machine running Windows? How?

Answer (score 4):

**Access throught ssh**
If you want a terminal access to your laptop, you can use SSH. For that, you need to install ssh server on your laptop and have an ssh client on your Windows machine.

On you laptop, install ssh server (and client)

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

On your windows machine, you can use a tool like [putty](http://www.putty.org/).

If you need an access to transfert file, you can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net). Using the same tool on server side.

**Access throught VNC**
If you prefer have a remote access to your desktop (more visual), you can use VNC.
In this case, install [vino](http://apt://vino). It is a VNC server.

```
sudo apt-get install vino
```

And use a VNC Desktop Remote Viewer like vinagre, or [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/) on Windows.

Comment: @JayKayKay If this was the solution to your issue please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and if you really like there answer give it an upvote too.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success remotely logging in over a local network using xrdp.  http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5382

As per suggestion, here's more detail on how to install and use xrdp including some customisation.  Example uses LXDE, adjust to taste...

XRDP install/config

- Install XRDP and LXDE desktop.  sudo apt-get install xrdp lxde
- Ensure a suitable keyboard mapping file is in place in /etc/xrdp.  For example, for UK source a file called km-0809.ini.  Ensure permissions/ownership are correct using sudo chown/chgrp user file.
- Also in /etc/xrdp, edit startwm.sh to comment out the line . /etc/X11/Xsession and add a line lxsession.
- Edit /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini to amend port=-1 to port=ask-1to enable the ability to select already running sessions.
- In /usr/share/xrdp customise ad24b.bmp and xrdp24b.bmp as required. Example, legal warning/notification in ad24b.bmp in a 140x140 size file.  The other file can contain any suitably sized background image.  As above, ensure ownership/permissions are correct.
- Perform a restart of xrdp before attempting a login.  sudo service xrdp restart

Comment: What I didn't understand was the client and server app to install. This link was also helpful http://www.howtogeek.com/124849/how-to-remote-control-your-home-computer-from-anywhere-with-vnc/